# Assign job count number to variable (POSIX-Shell)

Tags: shell, posix, variable-assignment, jobs, ash

Opening 3 jobs in ash with i.e.

```
sh & sh & sh &
```

and counting this jobs with i.e.

```
jobs -p | wc -l
```

shows

```
3
```

which is OK.
But trying to assign this job count to a variable with

```
JOBNR=$(jobs -p | wc -l)
```

and printing this variable with

```
echo $JOBNR
```

shows

```
0
```

Why? Maybe during the assignment a new Shell (without jobs) was opened?
What could be the best solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for my problem - doing it by stages and with attention to quotes:
`JOBNR=$(jobs -p); JOBNR=$(echo "$JOBNR" | wc -w); echo $JOBNR`
does the job.

The first expression does the raw job and stores a list (with some lines) in `JOBNR`.

Echoing `$JOBNR` (with quotes (!) because of more than one line stored in `JOBNR`) and counting the words with `wc` could be (re)assigned to `JOBNR` the "regular" way (`VAR=$(command)`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a matter of how the shell implements the command substitution. In `bash`, `JOBNR` gets the value 3, but in `dash`, 0.

Comment: A similar assignment seems to work:VAR=$(ls | wc -l) provides with echo $VAR the number of files (16).

Comment: Those are external commands; `jobs` is a shell-builtin, so which shell actually executes it determines what its output is.

Comment: Could it be possible to pipe or stream the output to a variable? Storing the output to a file with `jobs -p | wc -l > tempfile` and a following `read VAR < tempfile` works fine but involving a file is not an optimal solution.

Comment: That suffers from the same problem in `dash`; `jobs -p` is run in a subshell induced by the pipe, and outputs 0.